# How to get user input to export to environment variables with makefile

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, makefile, environment-variables

I want to create a makefile which will ask users to input info and then export them as environment variables example of region, access key, access id for AWS account.

I have tried below but no luck. where am i doing wrong?

```
build:  
    read -p "Enter a Region:" region;  
    echo export TF_VAR_region=$$region
    echo export PKR_VAR_region=$$TF_VAR_region
```

Comment: Each line of a recipe is executed in *its own* shell.  The variables you set in one are lost when that one terminates.

Comment: But more generally, what you're doing wrong is trying to have `make` solicit interactive input.  Although it's possible to make that work, it's a poor idea for a variety of reasons.  Have users run some kind of pre-build configuration script instead, or instruct them to edit the needed information into a file -- maybe even the makefile itself.